# Is there a name for the points on the body of electric guitars?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, terminology

I was trying to describe a part of the guitar to a friend a I could not come up with the proper name for it. I was try to refer to the two points on the body of an electric guitar where typically part of the strap typically goes on one side. I've included a picture and circled the parts on the guitar that I'm referring to.

[image]

Is there a proper name for those parts of the guitar?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name; I've heard people call them 'horns', especially when referring to Gibson SGs

Comment: See also [What is a "horn" on a bass guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50235)

Answer (score 11):

They are indeed called horns. In the 60s/70s, Burns made some electric guitars called Black Bison, I seem to remember,and the horns did resemble those of a bison.The cutaway is necessary to reach higher frets, but if the horns were removed as well, the balance of the instrument would be compromised even more. Besides which,as you say, most manufacturers need the top horn to fit the strap button to.

Comment: I've seen a guitar or three without horns and they look *ugly* (I don't mean flying V or voyager style designs, I mean ones that would have horns but the horn is cut off) - somehow we've been programmed over the last 100+ years to need some of that classic guitar shape to be retained even with a double cutaway. Even ESP LTD guitars with just very small horns don't look right.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - true, and there's really no need for a top horn, although aesthetics dictate there could be. I guess Mr. Fender started it all back in the 50s. Where that idea came from, who knows?

Comment: I wonder if the double horn came about because of lefties playing right handed guitars upside down.

Comment: Doubtful, as the majority of lefties would expect the whole thing to be mirror image. Excepting Jimi, of course, who really didn't mind which way the guitar was. Good job he had a preference for Strats - or was that why?

Comment: Les Claypool had Carl Thompson build him a custom 6-string and actually had to have them rework it to include a longer horn to balance the instrument.  I think the balance consideration is a little more important on basses since they have a longer scale (more leverage) and are heavier in general, not to say that it's not important on guitars.

Comment: @Basstickler - that's fair. On six of my basses, the top horn is level with about fret 14, and they all balance really well. It also puts the strap button in a good place - with a shorter horn, it would tip.

Comment: @Tim: Hendrix did later in his career play some flying V's (more symmetric) and actual lefthand models, but he always seemed to prefer the old righty Strats overall; so this is apparently not just due to the Strat's swapping-suitability.

Comment: Agreed, @Basstickler. The "balance" of the guitar on your leg is much more apparent to me with a bass than with a guitar.

Answer (score 5):

They're called horns:

[image]

The indentations next to them (beside the neck) are referred to as cutouts or cutaways, and are usually more often what is referenced in relation to the general shape of a guitar body. In the image I've provided, the guitar is a single cutaway, and the image you have shown is a double cutaway.

Comment: Did you make up 'tricep'? Never heard of that one!

Comment: I did not make this image, and I have not heard "tricep" anymore than I've heard "Jackhole". :P

Comment: Yes, jackhole did sound a little out of order - it's always been a jack socket to me. Although after explaining to a student that the plug was called a jack, he asked if the corresponding part on the guitar was Jill...

Comment: I always understood the socket to be the jack, and the type of plug that mates with a jack can be referred to as a jack plug. OED agrees: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jack

Comment: @Dedwards You may not have made this image, but it does not make it correct. The only parts that are correct are the joint, shoulder, waist and horn. Everything else is entirely fictional, made up by whoever made the image.