# What is a "horn" on a bass guitar?

Tags: terminology, electric-bass-guitar

What is a "horn" on a bass guitar?  I saw a tag at Guitar Center on a bass guitar that said it was discounted because of a "cracked horn" and "reglued horn".

I have a screenshot of the tag if needed.

Comment: See also [Is there a name for the points on the body of electric guitars?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/46087)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The uppermost part of the guitar body, from where it leaves the neck to where, in most cases, the strap button is screwed in. So called as its shape resembles a horn (cow's, that is). As it's usually quite thin, unprotected, and the grain may go the wrong way, it's vulnerable to knocks. Once refitted, it won't make any difference to the sound or performance of the bass.

Comment: See the [Danelectro Longhorn Bass](https://danelectro.com/product/baritone-bass/) to see some really bovine horns on a bass guitar.